# $M=M_1\cup M_2$ is not necessarily a manifold, when $M_1\cap M_2=\emptyset$, $M_i$ a manifold

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

While $M_1\cap M_2=\emptyset$, $M_i$ a manifold, show $M=M_1\cup M_2$ is not necessarily a manifold.

Another question, prior to this one, was to show the union is a manifold, where the conditions were slightly different: one manifold was to be disjoint from the other's closure. So I believe I should be looking at intervals that are open, semi-open, closed, etc, within the coordinates in a space of bigger dimension. I am just afraid I am not too familiar with manifolds. One definition states that $M$ is a $k$-manifold near $x_0\in \Bbb{R}^n$ if there exists a permutation $(i_1,...,i_n)$ of $\{1,...,n\}$ and a mapping $g$, continuously differentiable near $({x_0}_{i_1},...,{x_0}_{i_k})$ such that: $$x\in M \iff g (x_{i_1},...,x_{i_k})=(x_{i_{n-k}},...,x_{i_n})$$.

So far, I looked at  $M=$ $x$-axis in $\Bbb{R}^2$, with the identity permutation and $g(x)=0$. For all $(x,y)$ on the $x$ axis, $M$, $y=0$, and therefore $g(x)=0=y=x_2$. I am not sure about how legal it is and about differentiability. Is there a way to proceed? I would really appreciate reference to my attempts.

Comment: How is the manifold structure defined on $M_1 \cup M_2$?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "manifold structure"... I didn't see such term in the notes. I will have another look at it.

Comment: This reminds me of the example of a figure eight, which is not a manifold even though it can be written as $f(I)$ where $I$ is an interval and $f$ is 1-1 and smooth.

Comment: So I should be creating a sort of intersection? 
I thought of an open interval $y\cdot (0,\infty)$. Is it something to work with?